# Why does Fira Code font look blurry in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts, fira-code

I want to use Fira Code in VS Code (Windows) and have already configured the font as explained in the [instructions](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/VS-Code-Instructions#manually-editing-settingsjson). 
Somehow, the font seems to look blurry. How can I fix that?

```
"editor.fontFamily": "'Fira Code'",
"editor.fontLigatures": true,
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to [install](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/VS-Code-Instructions#manually-editing-settingsjson) TTF [for Windows (and Linux)](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/issues/798#issuecomment-544515645) - ***not*** OTF. A blurry font likely indicates, that the wrong font type is chosen.

#### Check (Windows 10):

- Type "font" in search panel and select Font settings

[image]

- Filter to Fira Code and click the panel

[image]

- Check for each font face, that font file has `".ttf"` extension

[image]

- If not (.otf), use the uninstall button and repeat font installation (now TTF).